# whole absent month-SQL DBMS

Tags: sql

I HAVE THE FOLLOWING TABLE **SALARY _MONTH** CONATIN THE FOLLOWING FILEDS(data-example):
[image]

PERSON CAN HAVE month salary(salary  every month)  depend on his absent in **(absent table)**
[image]

what i should to do is show the person that be absent whole month  with his salary  (person  can have more an absent kod and  have  diffent date   ) how i can read en whole month absent ?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: BTW. tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: i know  it is easier if i used  sample data but i donnot know how to do it 1

Comment: i know  it is easier if i used  sample data but i donnot know how to do it !  for DBMS I cannot  identify  because i work in Form from program that we use sql query only no update  delete just small window   . you have right about field  but i wrote it as  misstake  i know  table contain of rows and column ... for my query  i  am so weak på date  function for this reason i didnot write any thing but if you want it i will add it bellow

Answer (score 0):

I can show an answer for SQL Server since you didn't specify a RDBMS. You should be able to adapt this technique for any RDBMS but will likely have to change the syntax. I would normally use common table expressions to make this look better, but since I don't know your RDBMS I will use subqueries so it will be more portable.

First, make sure that for `SALARY_MONTH` that the `DATE_E` column contains the last day of the month. In your sample data the `DATE_E` value for May 2019 was shown as 2019-05-30 and it should be 2019-05-31. If this was a typo, no problem but if you do not store the last day of the month in the `DATE_E` column of `SALARY_MONTH`, you will have to adapt this technique.

I will set up a script with some data so we can look at results:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #SALARY_MONTH;
CREATE TABLE #SALARY_MONTH(
    PER_ID INT NOT NULL, 
    SALARY DECIMAL(6, 2) NOT NULL, 
    DATE_S DATE NOT NULL, 
    DATE_E DATE NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #SALARY_MONTH(PER_ID,SALARY,DATE_S,DATE_E)
VALUES 
(3, 5000.00, '2019-05-01', '2019-05-31'), -- make sure that DATE_E is the last day of the month!
(3, 4300.00, '2019-06-01', '2019-06-30'), 
(3, 4900.00, '2019-07-01', '2019-07-31'), 
(3, 5200.00, '2019-08-01', '2019-08-31')

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Absent;
CREATE TABLE #ABSENT(
    PER_ID INT NOT NULL, 
    [Absent-kod] INT NOT NULL, 
    DATE_S DATE NOT NULL, 
    DATE_E DATE NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #ABSENT(PER_ID,[Absent-kod],DATE_S,DATE_E)
VALUES 
(3, 43, '2019-05-01', '2019-05-12'), -- absent all of May 2019
(3, 14, '2019-05-13', '2019-05-31'), 
(3, 43, '2019-06-05', '2019-06-07'), -- not absent all of June 2019
(3, 13, '2019-07-01', '2019-07-06'),
(3, 13, '2019-07-07', '2019-07-16'), -- absent all of July 2019
(3, 13, '2019-07-17', '2019-07-25'),
(3, 13, '2019-07-26', '2019-07-29'),
(3, 13, '2019-07-30', '2019-07-31'),
(3, 43, '2019-08-01', '2019-08-30'); -- not absent all of August 2019
```

First, we can query `SALARY_MONTH` and create new columns for the month, the year, and the number of days in the month:

```sql
SELECT PER_ID, SALARY, DATE_S, DATE_E, 
MONTH(DATE_S) AS [MONTH], YEAR(DATE_S) AS [YEAR], 
DAY(EOMONTH(DATE_S)) AS [DAYS_IN_MONTH] 
FROM #SALARY_MONTH
```

The result with the data I used is:

| PER_ID | SALARY | DATE_S | DATE_E | MONTH | YEAR | DAYS_IN_MONTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5000.00 | 2019-05-01 | 2019-05-31 | 5 | 2019 | 31 |
| 3 | 4300.00 | 2019-06-01 | 2019-06-30 | 6 | 2019 | 30 |
| 3 | 4900.00 | 2019-07-01 | 2019-07-31 | 7 | 2019 | 31 |
| 3 | 5200.00 | 2019-08-01 | 2019-08-31 | 8 | 2019 | 31 |

This will be handy for determining if somebody was absent for a whole month. Next, we need a query that will show us the number of days an employee was absent each month:

```sql
SELECT PER_ID, SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, DATE_S, DATE_E) + 1) AS [DAYS_ABSENT], 
MONTH(DATE_S) AS [MONTH], YEAR(DATE_S) AS [YEAR]
FROM #ABSENT 
GROUP BY PER_ID, MONTH(DATE_S), YEAR(DATE_S)
```

And the results are:

| PER_ID | DAYS_ABSENT | MONTH | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 31 | 5 | 2019 |
| 3 | 3 | 6 | 2019 |
| 3 | 31 | 7 | 2019 |
| 3 | 30 | 8 | 2019 |

With these two queries in place, we can now `INNER JOIN` them together when the `EMP_ID`, `MONTH`, and `YEAR` are the same and we only want to see records where `DAYS_ABSENT` is the same as `DAYS_IN_MONTH`. Putting this together we get the answer:

```sql
SELECT emp.PER_ID, emp.SALARY, emp.[MONTH], emp.[YEAR] FROM 
(
    SELECT PER_ID, SALARY, DATE_S, DATE_E, 
    MONTH(DATE_S) AS [MONTH], YEAR(DATE_S) AS [YEAR], 
    DAY(EOMONTH(DATE_S)) AS [DAYS_IN_MONTH] 
    FROM #SALARY_MONTH
) AS emp 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT PER_ID, SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, DATE_S, DATE_E) + 1) AS [DAYS_ABSENT], 
    MONTH(DATE_S) AS [MONTH], YEAR(DATE_S) AS [YEAR]
    FROM #ABSENT 
    GROUP BY PER_ID, MONTH(DATE_S), YEAR(DATE_S)
) AS absence ON absence.PER_ID = emp.PER_ID AND absence.[MONTH] = emp.[Month] AND absence.[YEAR] = emp.[Year]
WHERE emp.DAYS_IN_MONTH = absence.DAYS_ABSENT;
```

And the final result is:

| PER_ID | SALARY | MONTH | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5000.00 | 5 | 2019 |
| 3 | 4900.00 | 7 | 2019 |

### Common Table Expressions in SQL Server

Here is the same thing but using common table expressions in case you are using SQL Server. There is no difference but I wanted to include it since it is how I originally wrote the answer.

```sql
;WITH EmployeeSalary AS (
    SELECT PER_ID, SALARY, DATE_S, DATE_E, 
    MONTH(DATE_S) AS [MONTH], YEAR(DATE_S) AS [YEAR], 
    DAY(EOMONTH(DATE_S)) AS [DAYS_IN_MONTH] 
    FROM #SALARY_MONTH
), MonthlyAbsence AS (
    SELECT PER_ID, SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, DATE_S, DATE_E) + 1) AS [DAYS_ABSENT], 
    MONTH(DATE_S) AS [MONTH], YEAR(DATE_S) AS [YEAR]
    FROM #ABSENT 
    GROUP BY PER_ID, MONTH(DATE_S), YEAR(DATE_S)
)
SELECT emp.PER_ID, emp.SALARY, emp.[MONTH], emp.[YEAR] 
FROM EmployeeSalary AS emp 
INNER JOIN MonthlyAbsence AS absence ON absence.PER_ID = emp.PER_ID AND absence.[MONTH] = emp.[Month] AND absence.[YEAR] = emp.[Year]
WHERE emp.DAYS_IN_MONTH = absence.DAYS_ABSENT;
```

And the results are the same.