# DATEDIFFT,EOMONTH and DATE format

Tags: sql, db2

what should be wrong with

```
SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, DATE_S, DATE_E) + 1)   
DATE_S and  DATE_E are DATE TYPE  and maybe DATE_E IS NULL
```

The second question is how i can get tha last day in the month i write

```
 DAY(EOMONTH(DATE_S))
```

DATE_S ='2019-05' how i can fix it i tried with concat but is doesnot work

Comment: `DAY(EOMONTH('2019-05' + '-01')) ` should work. For the first part, tell us what date_s and date_e look like.

Comment: THEY LOOK  LIK 2029-10-19 IT IS DATE TYPE

Comment: `SUM(DATEDIFF(...` should work as expected then.

Comment: as i know  put i get a fel  !

Comment: @iman . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @iman "DATE_S ='2019-05'", it's not a date then

Comment: DATE_S ='2019-05 ' Iit is for the senond question the firts question the date format is  2019-10-27

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @GordonLinoff db2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a question about an answer I gave yesterday on the question  [whole absent month-SQL DBMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68937856/whole-absent-month-sql-dbms/68939173#68939173) . You should comment on the answer for continuity's sake.

You ask what should be wrong with:

```sql
SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, DATE_S, DATE_E) + 1)
```

You mention that `DATE_E` may be `NULL`. This portion of the query is for the `ABSENT` table. If you do not not the end of an employee's absence, then what should you do? You can add a `WHERE` clause and ignore the employees who have the end absence date (maybe because they have no returned to work), or you could default it to today, or you can perform some other action you deem appropriate.

To ignore the values:

```sql
SELECT PER_ID, SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, DATE_S, DATE_E) + 1) AS [DAYS_ABSENT], 
MONTH(DATE_S) AS [MONTH], YEAR(DATE_S) AS [YEAR]
FROM #ABSENT 
WHERE DATE_E IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY PER_ID, MONTH(DATE_S), YEAR(DATE_S);
```

To default to today:

```sql
SELECT PER_ID, SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, DATE_S, COALESCE(DATE_E, GETDATE())) + 1) AS [DAYS_ABSENT], 
MONTH(DATE_S) AS [MONTH], YEAR(DATE_S) AS [YEAR]
FROM #ABSENT 
GROUP BY PER_ID, MONTH(DATE_S), YEAR(DATE_S);
```

Finally, to get the last day of the month is simply

```sql
EOMONTH(DATE_S)
```

If the value of `DATE_S` is actually something like `2019-05`, then it must not be a `DATE` (because that is not a valid `DATE`) but rather a text of some type. We know there is always a day one of the month, so you can do this which works:

```sql
DECLARE @data VARCHAR(10) = '2019-05';
SELECT EOMONTH(CONCAT(@data, '-01')) AS [LastDayOfMonth];
```

In the answer to [whole absent month-SQL DBMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68937856/whole-absent-month-sql-dbms/68939173#68939173) I used `DAY(EOMONTH(DATE_S))` because it is about the easiest way to get the number of days in a month - find the last day in the month and then get the day for it, that is the number of days in the month.

Please mark answers as accepted if they solve your question, and comment on answers if you want more clarification.

Comment: exakt - this is about you answer and i would to thank you  to give me new info

Comment: @iman happy to give you new info, what is your question? There is new info in the answer above.

Comment: This is what i  mean. You with your answer yesterday and today give me new info thanks

Comment: @iman sorry, I misunderstood you... hope this helps with your query, good luck!

Comment: @iman: you should accept the answers that solved your problem

Comment: SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, DATE_S, DATE_E) + 1) AS [DAYS_ABSENT] how i  can write it  in DB2 as RDBMS   and it the same for EOMONTH i cannot use them ! please  @BjorgP have you any idea ! i am sorry

Comment: @Tick_Tack I don't use DB2 but a quick Google search shows that there is a LAST_DAY function that should work instead of EOMONTH https://www.ibm.com/docs/ko/db2-for-zos/12?topic=functions-last-day and a DAYS function instead of DATEDIFF https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=functions-days Sorry I cannot help you more, I do not have a DB2 server anywhere to try things out